# how can i access a folder or file in parent folder php

Tags: php, html, shared-directory

i want a shared folder which contains images to be accessed by html pages inside sub folders.(child folders)

Answer (score 11):

If you mean your html folder and images folder are siblings, you're probably looking for the `..` directory... um, thingy.

Your files look like:

```
/www
    /html
        index.php
    /images
        myimage.png
```

Write an img tag like this:

```
<img src="../images/myimage.png" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Make a folder inside your website and put images into it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two ways of linking to a resource (page/script/image/whatever):

- Use an absolute link: `http://www.yourserver.com/path/to/resource.jpg`
- Use a relative link: for example, to go from `http://www.yourserver.com/path/from/page.html` to `http://www.yourserver.com/path/to/resource.jpg`, you use `../to/resource.jpg`

So just put your images on a publicly accessibly folder, and refer to them using one of those two methods.

Or refine your question :)

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you have a folder with many folders inside, and inside does many folder you have html pages, and you want does pages to access the first folder...

main_folder

pic.png

pic.gif

pic.jpg

sub_folder

```
html_page.php
```

just use ../pic.png when you call the image file from the html_page.php

Was this what you where looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the directory of the current file with the [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) funciton:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

If you want the parent directory you can use '..' thus:

```
$current_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$parent_dir = $current_dir.'/..';
```